# how to "debug as maven test" in eclipse (sts)

Tags: eclipse, debugging, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I have written test cases in JUnit and they are executing fine when I use run as - maven test. But although I put debug points and select **debug as - maven test**, debugging does not work. I use maven-surefire-plugin. I am running the test cases in eclipse (STS) itself, there is no need for remote debug on an application running in server. These are simple test cases, testing some application code. Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run the JUnit test directly in STS also for debugging. So no need to start Maven for that purpose.
Click on the Test Class you would like to debug. Right mouse button -> Debug As -> JUnit shoud do the trick.

Comment: I did try.Its the way I tried actually.Although I put debug points,the execution does not stop there.